# Return IntPtr with array to c++

Tags: c#, unmanaged, unmarshalling

I have c# method ReadBytesInTask, which is called from c++ code, using function pointer acquired with Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate method.

ReadBytesInTask gets ptr to unmanaged short[] array populates it and sends back to unmanaged code. Array is unmarshalled to unmanaged memory correctly inside method, but c++ gets only zero populated array.
What should I do?

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private delegate int BytesReader([In,Out] IntPtr buffer, int samplesCount, string taskId);

private static readonly BytesReader _readBytesInTask = ReadBytesInTask;

private static int ReadBytesInTask(IntPtr buffer, int samplesCount)
{
    var bufferSize = samplesCount;              
    var samplesToRead = bufferSize <= task.Buffer.Length - task.Offset ? bufferSize : task.Buffer.Length - task.Offset;

    buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(short))*samplesToRead);
    Marshal.Copy(task.Buffer, task.Offset, buffer, samplesToRead);

    task.Offset += samplesToRead;
    if (samplesToRead < bufferSize) task.Offset = 0;
    return samplesToRead;
}
```

Comment: If you want to be able to modify `buffer` in your code, perhaps you need to declare it as `ref`?

Comment: Well, it is already pointer to unmanaged memory, and it doesn't change. Changes memory on its other end.

Comment: Actually, it _does_ change: `buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(...`

Comment: The code makes little sense.  It cannot compile, ReadBytesInTask is missing the 3rd string argument.  Nor does allocating "buffer" make sense, you are not returning that buffer pointer to the native code.  Best guess is that the native code has already allocated the buffer, it tells you how big it is with the samplesCount argument.  Which you should not ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the pointer and not what it points to. So you will need a pointer to pointer. So it would be something like this:

```
private static int ReadBytesInTask(IntPtr* buffer, int samplesCount)
```